# HTML5 console client for AWS EC2 via API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I see that you can connect to an AWS EC2 via SSH or a Java plugin. Is there a way to access the EC2 image via an HTML5 client that does not require a java plugin?

Is there a way to connect to an EC2 VM via the EC2 API?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [FireSSH](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/firessh/mcognlamjmofcihollilalojnckfiajm?hl=en) Chrome application, using it on my Chromebook and it works fine. It also allows importing the PEM file (other clients require that you convert the keys first).